# Trouble escaping a period inside String.matches() method

Tags: java, regex, escaping, period

I'm getting a compilation error when I use this regular expression inside the String class's matches() method. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
String email = "this@that.com";
System.out.println(email.matches("^(.+@.+\.\\w{2,4})$"));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

escape period `.` with two backslashes `\\.` valid escape sequences supported in java are  `\b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\`

```
System.out.println(email.matches("^(.+@.+\\.\\w{2,4})$"));
```

OR:

Enclose it within `\\Q` and `\\E`

```
\\Q.\\E
```